# How to create a blocking queue in C between different threads on Linux platform

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Here is the pseudo code:

```
int flag = 0;

int thread_send (void)
{
    create_thread( thread_receive );  /* use pthread_create() in the real code */
    sleep (10);
    flag = 1;
}

int thread_receive (void)
{
    while ( flag != 1 ) {} ;
    printf ("the flag is set to 1");
}
```

I want to get the signal (an `int` type) from the other thread, so what can I create a blocking queue in C99 ?

This is the concept map: [image]

Comment: Check out event counters and sequencers.

Comment: Design question: too broad. Please post a specific almost-working piece of code you're having problem with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pthread_mutex_t`. Receiving thread should call`pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_mutex)` on a shared (global) instance of pthread_mutex_t. This will block Receiving thread. When Sending thread calls `pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_mutex)` the Receiving thread will unblock automatically.

Here's sample code.

```
pthread_mutex_t shared_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int flag = 0;

int thread_send (void)
{
   pthread_mutex_lock( &shared_mutex ); // make sure to lock before creating thread_receive
   create_thread( thread_receive );  /* use pthread_create() in the real code */
   sleep (10);
   flag = 1;
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &shared_mutex );
}
int thread_receive (void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_mutex); 
    if(flag == 1) 
    {
        printf ("the flag is set to 1");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &shared_mutex );
}
```